# <script async > vs document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].insertBefore etc.?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, pageload

Is there any material difference between:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js" async></script>
```

and

```
(function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script'); 
  s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  s.async = true; 
  s.src = 'script.js'; 
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
  x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x)
;})();
```

?

Comment: Why would you want to do the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only quote [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Async_support):

> In older browsers that don't support the `async` attribute, parser-inserted scripts block the parser; script-inserted scripts execute asynchronously in IE and WebKit, but synchronously in Opera and pre-4.0 Firefox.

So in other words, the second one will still evaluate the script asynchronously in older IE and WebKit browsers.